# Process attach multiple stdins

Tags: node.js, stdin, child-process, spawn

I have one process, which can receive two stdin's

```
this.child = child_process.spawn(
    'command',
    [ '-', 'pipe:3' ],
    { 'stdio' => [null, null, null, ???unknown] } 
);

this.child.stdin.write(data);

this.child.stdio[3]??.write(anotherData); //This is the unknown part.
```

Is it possible to create two stdins, without creating another child process?

Problem explanation: My problem actually is with ffmpeg, I'm spawning ffmpeg instance with audio input and video input, and they both need separate input pipe's ,e.g., pipe:0 (stdin) is for video, and pipe:3 (another stdin, but for audio data), because pipe:1 (stdout), and pipe:2 (stderr

Comment: Can you use the [`stdio` option](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio) of [`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options)?

Comment: I can use, but how? Thaths the `???unknown` part